# ¿Como me puedo conectar mi aplicación android a un arduino mediante bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Este es mi código, pero no me funciona al seleccionar una dirección MAC para conectarse y no resulta la conexión:

```
private ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String address = null;
private UUID MyUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
private boolean isBtConnected = false;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String str = (String) mArrayAdapter.getItem(i);
            address = str;
            new ConnectBT().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private boolean connectSuccess = true; // Por si no funciona, es que ya estaba conectado

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main2Activity.this, "Conectando...","Por favor espere");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {
        try{
            if(bluetoothSocket == null) {
                bluetoothAdapter =BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                bluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MyUUID);
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectSuccess =false;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!connectSuccess) {
            msg("fallo en la conexion");
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            finish();
        } else {
            msg("Conectado");
            isBtConnected = true;
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private void msg(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Te comparto el código que utilicé yo para conectar a un módulo CZ-HC-05, es bastante antiguo el código pero puedes echarle un vistazo a ver si te sirve: https://github.com/amendezcabrera/my-car-controller/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/dolphinziyo/carcontroller/MainActivity.java Tenía algunos errores al conectar por segunda vez si no me equivoco, pero la conexión y el envío de comandos lo realiza

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvio de mucho